# Routing Issue, Calling Controller based on Variables in URL- Laravel 4

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, laravel-routing

I am developing an application with Laravel 4 what I need to do is this:
let's say I have the following route:

```
  Route::get('/myroute/{entity}/methodname',

  );
```

Inside it I need to decide based on the entity variable which Controller and method should be called for example:

```
 'MyNameSpace\MyPackage\StudentController@methodname'
```

if the

```
entity == Student
```

and call the

```
  'MyNameSpace\MyPackage\StaffController@methodname'
```

if the

```
    entity == Staff
```

how in can be done in Laravel 4 routing is it possible at all or I have to come up with 2 different routes anyway like?

```
    Route::get('/myroute/Student/methodname') and Route::get('/myroute/Staff/methodname')
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This should fit your need

```
Route::get('/myroute/{entity}/methodname', function($entity){
    $controller = App::make('MyNameSpace\\MyPackage\\'.$entity.'Controller');
    return $controller->callAction('methodname', array());
}
```

Now to avoid errors, lets also check if the controller and action exists:

```
Route::get('/myroute/{entity}/methodname', function($entity){
    $controllerClass = 'MyNameSpace\\MyPackage\\'.$entity.'Controller';
    $actionName = 'methodname';
    if(method_exists($controllerClass, $actionName.'Action')){
        $controller = App::make($controllerClass);
        return $controller->callAction($actionName, array());
    }
}
```

#### Update

To automate the process a bit more you can even make the action name dynamic

```
Route::get('/myroute/{entity}/{action?}', function($entity, $action = 'index'){
    $controllerClass = 'MyNameSpace\\MyPackage\\'.$entity.'Controller';

    $action = studly_case($action) // optional, converts foo-bar into FooBar for example
    $methodName = 'get'.$action; // this step depends on how your actions are called (get... / ...Action)

    if(method_exists($controllerClass, $methodName)){
        $controller = App::make($controllerClass);
        return $controller->callAction($methodName, array());
    }
}
```

Comment: You're welcome. Also, if you want your action name to be dynamic, just pass wrap it in `{` `}` in the route definition, pass it in as "actionName" and remove `$actionName = 'methodname'` ;)

Comment: lukasgeiter, you had already answered my question, if you also let me know how to call a Controller without specifying function of it , I'll be very thankful for example:  Route::get('/myroute/{entity}/',

  );
will call the EntityController automatically

Comment: @Siavosh You mean `myroute/entity/` should call the `index` action ?

Comment: based on my understanding if inside the EntityController there is a function getMethodname(), and the route  '/myroute/{entity}/methodname' will be automatically called that methof of Controller

Comment: callAction() was just what I was looking for, thanks @lukasgeiter!