# One route for multiple controllers

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I'am new to Laravel 5 and have one small problem with routing.
I would like to be able to set one route for multiple controllers.
Lets say I have controlers: one, two, three.
I want to create something like (that is not working of course):

```
Route::get('{controller}', $controller.'@index')->where('controller', '(one| two|three)+');
```

So when I will type:

```
examlpe.com/two
```

It will call controller two and index method, and it will work in same way for one and three controllers, but not for others (this is why I used 'where' here).

What I am trying to do:
I have to create an app divided to 20 or even more profiles. 
Each profile will be used by different users working on different datasets (dataset for group 'one' will be never available for group 'two', etc.).
Each profile will use similiar main functions (about 4-5), but there will be many differences between them (mostly some rules that will have an influence to the function results and dataset presentation).
I can 'extract' core of those functions to the single controller that will be extended by controlers dedicated to each group so then I will be able to adjust functions results to each profile (according to those users needs).
My idea was to have it all separated per profile so then I will have profiles like in example: one, two, three, ...
Then each profile will have slighlty different url so it will be easily recognized, and will contain also dataset id, for ex. (process, view, closed are methods from controller, available for all group, but have some differences as I wrote before):

```
examlpe.com/two/process/12
examlpe.com/two/view/34
examlpe.com/one/process/66
examlpe.com/three/closed/54
```

Hope that is clear...

Comment: Why are you trying to call three controllers through one route? Maybe just get one controller and then fire off an event or dispatch a command to your application

Comment: Just fire one method in one controller and inside that method do everything (or fire a houndred other methods if you need).

Comment: Looks like a typical [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). Since `one`, `two` and `three` predefined anyway just register three separate routes.

Comment: Take a look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/26759308/1903366)